export model from solidworks to blender with join point
i have models rendered in solidworks and i need to export them to blender(not a problem). but some models have "kinematics" that will need to be used for inverse kinematics. how can this information be exported to blender?

What export settings have you tried so far? Can you export from SolidWorks using multiple kinds of files?

Officially, FBX does support constraints, including IK. Concerning SolidWorks' ability to export constraints and Blender's ability to import them, I can't find much information about the former, and the latter is unheard of. To this day, exporting constraints is pretty much not even considered feasible outside the Autodesk ecosystem. If it's already animated, anyone would just bake the animation into keyframes and export that instead. If not animated, just build the IK systems in Blender.
